# Отправка данных AXAJ+JSON+PHP почему не проходит?

Tags: php, jquery

Уже что только не прочитал, не могу понять как объявить переменную, которую нужно принять для того, чтоб распарсить в PHP строку. Ну или в jQuery что-то не то?

```
    var button=$("button");
button.click( function (){
    var data = $("form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "registration.php",
        dataType:"json",
        data: data,
        success: function () {
            alert(data);
            console.log(data);
        },
    });
});
```

в PHP что должно быть? непонятно какую переменную вписать сюда

```
echo json_decode(СЮДА);
```

Comment: $_POST['<любой NAME из передаваемой формы>']

Comment: Не то что то не отрабатывается alert по success да и вообще не помогло(

Comment: ТУпой jQuery 3.2.1 нормально не работает!!!

Comment: Какой стабильной версией пользуетесь народ? и как настроить кодировку ато кракозяюры лезут.

Comment: В `function ( data ) { colnsole.log(data)}`

Answer (score 1):

Вот шаблон скрипта:

```
if ($_POST) { // eсли пeрeдaн мaссив POST
  $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]); // пишeм дaнныe в пeрeмeнныe и экрaнируeм спeцсимвoлы
  $phone = htmlspecialchars($_POST["phone"]);
  $address = htmlspecialchars($_POST["address"]);
  // делаем что-то полезное в скрипте
  // в $json записываем ответ, который хотим вернуть в JS
  echo json_encode($json); // вывoдим мaссив oтвeтa
}
```

В HTML форма с полями, у которых атрибут `name` равен `name`, `phone` и `address`.

Comment: ну тогда еще и принимашку если можно плиз(

Comment: @ДимаПерильман в `success:` укажите вместо `function()` `function(data)`

Comment: @Byulent я еще в PHP не передал даные Не пойму как их принять речь пока об посылании шла

Answer (score 0):

В PHP сделай просто:

```
$name = 'Вася Пупкин';
$age = 30;

$data['name'] = $name;
$data['age'] = $age;

echo json_encode($data);
```

А на клиенте в ajax когда ловишь, то в аргументе callback-функции принимай data или как-нибудь по-другому ее можно обозвать. У тебя сейчас отсутсвует аргумент у callback-функции для success. Должно быть так:

```
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data.name); //Вася Пупкин
    console.log(data.age); //30
},
```

Comment: Это уже из PHP в JS а я еще из JS в PHP в нормальной кодировке не передал. Причем в консоль передается но как принять????? загадка.

Comment: Попробуй использовать seriallizeArray() вместо seriallize(); И на сервере в $_POST['имя_поле']='Значение' будут имена полей и значения

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: name , хотя в PHP указано echo json_decode($_POST["name"]);

Comment: В $data['name']= $_POST["name"]; сначала присвой. А потом echo json_encode($data);

Comment: не понял по какому имени послыются данные в PHP по $data['name]?